# how to savethe URLs visited by a laravel user

Tags: laravel

Is there a way to track the activity of users connected to Laravel? I want to know details like the pages visited and the time spent for each page by a user.

Answer (score 0):

These info are already saved by web server software you use. For example, Nginx save it in access log. It is often situated in `/var/log/nginx/access.log` file.

> NGINX writes information about client requests in the access log right
>   after the request is processed. By default, the access log is located
>   at `/var/log/nginx/access.log`, and the information is written to the
>   log in the predefined combined format. You can override the default
>   settings and change the format of logged messages by editing the NGINX
>   configuration file (`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` by default).

If it is apache, you can find it in apache configurations. Or more on this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38978/where-are-apache-file-access-logs-stored).

Answer (score 0):

The information provided by the server log can be augmented by implementing one of the free analytics services, such as Google Analytics.

Note that it's an invasion of privacy to track individuals, and may be against the law in some countries, especially if you don't give users the option to opt out of this data collection.